# Android - Navigation clear back stack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Jetpack Navigation. My action flow: Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C.

If I use

```
findNavController().backStack.clear()
```

clear all back stack, in Fragment C, I pressed back button and nothing to happen (because I cleared all back stack)

In Fragment C, I use this code

```
val currentBackStackEntry = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry
findNavController().backStack.clear()
findNavController().backStack.add(currentBackStackEntry)
```

purpose: clear back stack but keep only Fragment C in back stack. But it's not working, in Fragment C, I can back still B and A. I just want clear all previous back stack, and from C, can't back.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not part of the public API; you can't use that API, nor does it do anything like what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you want to use popUpTo to your root, and possibly make use of the inclusive arg.

Answer (score 0):

In your navigation directory add :

add to action element A to B and also B to C.

```
 app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

and remove

```
findNavController().backStack.clear()
```